# RAM problem when migrating Oracle DBs onto new server

Tags: oracle, migration

Sorry for posting this again but the old post has been locked for serveral days now and i can‘t add any new details on there.

We have multiple Oracle databases on an old server and want to migrate them to a newer sever with better CPU and more RAM.

However, when we try to do so, we cannot start the dbs on the new server as it throws following error: ORA-00838.

At the old server, a db with a 1000 processes assigned to it works with 1024M RAM as MEMORY_TARGET and the same db suddenly requires a MEMORY_TARGET of 2128M RAM on the new server.

Problem is, if we set all the dbs to the correct RAM, the RAM on the new server is already fully taken, actually exceeded. If we lower the number of processes however we save only very little RAM. Thus just lowering the processes doesn’t really help (and we can only do it to a certain amount anyway).

Does anybody have an idea what could cause this doubling of RAM-requirement for the new server? And how to fix it?

Important differences between the servers are as follows:

change of CPU: Intel to AMD more cores in the new server: 6 to 16 more RAM in the new server: 192 to 256GB

Old and new server: CentOS 7 64Bit, Oracle 12c Standard (12.1.0.1)

Migration of dbs: Using rsync to transfer dbs, then trying to restart them.

SGA_TARGET and PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET was set to 0 in the pfile of both servers but shows specific values when rechecking it- are these parameters hardware depenend?

**Parameters set when creating the DB:**

ALTER SYSTEM SET SHARED_POOL_SIZE = 0 scope=both;

ALTER SYSTEM SET LARGE_POOL_SIZE = 0 scope=both;

ALTER SYSTEM SET JAVA_POOL_SIZE = 0 scope=both;

ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_CACHE_SIZE = 0 scope=both;

ALTER SYSTEM SET STREAMS_POOL_SIZE = 0 scope=both;

ALTER SYSTEM SET SGA_TARGET = 0 scope=both;

ALTER SYSTEM SET PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET = 0 scope=both;

**Checking the parameters on the old (always the first) versus new server later on:**

db_cache_size=134217728

db_cache_size=96468992

large_pool_size=138412032

large_pool_size=520093696

pga_aggregate_target=373293056

pga_aggregate_target=138412032

sga_target=700448768

sga_target=935329792

shared_pool_size=411041792

shared_pool_size=301989888

our admin also tried to get the cpu_count (as this was suggested as difference between the servers that might influence the RAM) but somehow each command returns an error:

**SQL> show parameter cpu;**

ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

Process ID: 0

Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

**SQL> select value from v$parameter where name like 'cpu_count';
select value from v$parameter where name like 'cpu_count'**

ERROR at line 1:

ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

Process ID: 0

Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

**SQL> select CPU_CORE_COUNT_CURRENT from V$LICENSE;
select CPU_CORE_COUNT_CURRENT from V$LICENSE**

ERROR at line 1:

ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

Process ID: 0

Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

Comment: The error indicates the database is down - Can you please check , is the database up and running. ps -ef|grep pmon

Comment: @sarat: Thanks for your answer! Yes, the database is down- as we cannot start it which is the problem. We checked if the single db can be started and it works- but with the overall RAM demand we cannot start all of the dbs. that's what we are trying to solve: why does the new server demand so much more RAM? We've been trying to set the parameters on the new server to the same values as on the old server by now instead of 0 but it didn#t solve the problem.